# Hadoop 2.x - [<IP>:50070/dfshealth.html] not working

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

Setup a hadoop-2.2.0 cluster with 2 NN's, 2 DN's.

Web URL works fine with :50070/dfshealth.jsp
However, it does not work with the new UI style via :50070/dfshealth.html

What gives? Is it that this version does not have the new UI?

Thank ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Apache jira is the one which you are asking about

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-5334   (Implement dfshealth.jsp in HTML pages)

If you look at the above Hadoop jira, you could see that the fix version is 2.3.0. Which means hadoop version 2.2.0 doesn't have the new UI.

Comment: Thanks! Can I upgrade from 2.2.0 to 2.3.0?